# Create a border around image when active/clicked

Tags: css, image, border

I want to let my website visitors select from 3 different images and what I want now is a border around the image when they selected, so basically **when it's active.**

I hope it's understandable what I am looking for. Can someone help me perhaps with that?

I've tried to find something on Google but had no luck.

Comment: I know it's VERY EASY I just don't know how to implement it. I just need a simple border style around the image which is clicked. Nothing more!

Comment: maybe so http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ww3ofL6c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is suitable?

```css
input{
    display: none;
}

label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
}
input:checked + label{
    border: 4px solid #f00;     
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="r1" name="radio" />
<label for="r1">
    <img src="http://www.auto.az/forum/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-1.jpg?_r=1431896518" alt="" />
</label>

<input type="radio" id="r2" name="radio" />
<label for="r2">
    <img src="http://www.auto.az/forum/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-1.jpg?_r=1431896518" alt="" />
</label>

<input type="radio" id="r3" name="radio" />
<label for="r3">
    <img src="http://www.auto.az/forum/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-1.jpg?_r=1431896518" alt="" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.....and i am assuming that 'image_class' is the css class for your images.

```
     $('.image_class').click(function() {  
     $('.image_class').css("border","none");    
     // this border from other  image   
$(this).css("border","1px solid grey");  
// add border to clicked image });
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I set it up so always only 1 image can have a border?

Comment: you just need to add same class name for all the images and this code will handle that

Comment: did you do as per sumit, Please keep some sample code how you are doing, so we can help as per your code

Comment: if this answer is relevant to your problem then please accept the answer....@AlecWildenstein

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use some jQuery to add a border style to the image being clicked.

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" />
</div>

$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid black');
});
```

[See the JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shootermatic/wjhmc0y3/)